# Displaying PDF and website in Windows

Tags: windows, api, winapi, pdf, browser

In Windows, is there a native way to display PDF files and simple websites?

On Mac, both tasks are very simple:

```
[[PDFView ...] setDocument:[PDFDocument ...]];

[[[WebView ...] mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest ...]];
```

Is there anything comparable on Windows? From which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing native in Windows for embedding a PDF document in an application.  You would have to host a third-party ActiveX/COM container, such as from Adobe Acrobat, to handle that.

For a webpage, you can [host Internet Explorer's WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752038.aspx) in your app.  Some third-party browsers, like Mozilla and FireFox, also support hosting in apps.

Or, you could use the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx) function to open a given document/url in its default external application instead of hosting it inside of your own app.

Comment: In the link above, there it also mentions "Trident" - if I wanted to use JavaScript as well, do I have to use "WebBrowser control" as you suggested or is it sufficient to use "Trident"? (The article says, that Trident is just for HTML and CSS, I just want to make sure...)

Comment: shdocvw.dll is a more complete webbrowser, whereas mshtml.dll is more of the backen parsing/processing engine. If you want to show webpages to a user, then you would use the shdocvw.dll WebBrowser.